# Решал сейчас задание егэ, на сайте пишется одно, получается другое, все перепробовал, но все равно не получилось, что я делаю не так?

Tags: python

Обозначим через m & n поразрядную конъюнкцию неотрицательных целых чисел m и n.

Так, например, 14 & 5 = 1110**2** & 0101**2** = 0100**2** = 4(само условие, 2 означает систему счисления)

```
x = bin(14)[2:]
y = bin(5)[2:]
y = "0" + y
print(x and y)
```

Вывод моего кода

```
0101
```

Comment: И какое отношение *логический* оператор `and` имеет к поразрядной конъюнкции (оно же побитовое «И»)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так оператор `and` - это логическое И, а не побитовое. Для побитового И можете использовать оператор `&`. Т.е.

```
x = 14
y = 5
print(x & y)
```